# Java Spring Import Excel to SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, database, import

I have code for importing 15.000 Row in Excel with Java Spring, it takes around 10 minutes in Production Environtment but in Development Environtment its only takes around 5 minutes, how can i enhance the performance? heres my code.

Flow Code :

1. Checking Row Excel is Clean to Save
2. Save to Database 1 by 1

start checking row excel

```
                    Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();
                    String uuidAsString = uuid.toString();
                    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    if(cellIndex==0) { 
                        ble.setA(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    } else if(cellIndex==1) {
                        ble.setB(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    } else if(cellIndex==2) { 
                        ble.setC(currentCell.getDateCellValue());
}
```

after start

```
blacklistExternalRepository.saveAll(lstBlacklistExternal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code posted is not complete so here is an idea with the following assumptions:

- the variable `today` can be calculated only once for a batch import
- the excel document has a regular format, that is, each row has at least three cells at indices 0, 1 and 2

With this in mind, you could do something like

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
List<BLE> bleList = new ArrayList<>(); // a list of ble objects
for (Row r : rows) {
    Iterator<Cell> cellsInRow = ... // get the cells in row r
    BLE ble = new BLE();
    ble.setA(cellsInRow.next().getStringCellValue());
    ble.setB(cellsInRow.next().getStringCellValue());
    ble.setC(cellsInRow.next().getDateCellValue());
    bleList.add(ble);
}
// do whatever you need to with the list of ble objects
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer, ill try this to improve my code performance